# Extra space under grouped UITableView in popovers on iOS 6

Tags: uitableview, ios6, popover

I have an app that displays various grouped UITableViews in popovers. Before I present the popover, I'm calling setContentSizeForViewInPopover on the tableViewController, and setting the height to tableViewController.tableView.contentSize.height.

This worked fine in iOS 5, but now on iOS 6 there is extra space under the last cell in the UITableView, as though there is footer. I could just subtract the height of the space when I call setContentSizeForViewInPopover, but this seems like a nasty hack.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is nearly the same answer as @Loks, but it's definitely cleaner.

There isn't any need to subclass the `UITableView`, but rather just set your table's footer like so:

```
[tableView setTableFooterView:[UIView new]];
```

This will remove the space at the bottom and it won't require the GPU to process another view. All this does is remove the extra lines from the table AND the extra space.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I have also experienced this.

Resolved it for now by subclassing UITableView and adding this within viewDidLoad

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f)];
```

I'd like a less hacky solution to this as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did the same thing but there must be a cleaner way to do it!

Comment: Works for me as well, though I have no idea why this is necessary.  I haven't found any documentation suggesting this change occurred in iOS6 - anyone else?

Comment: Well, you could use `[UIView new]`, instead. It's not really much less hack-ish, but it does prevent the GPU from having to process drawing another view, since the `UIView` has a `frame` of `CGRectZero`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is an annoying issue. You can use `contentInset` to compensate the 20px extra bottom margin:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -20, 0);
```